# Symfony2-[Form]Collection given an array instead of an entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have some problem with collection type in symfony form. I tried to follow this guide http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/form/form_collections.html, but Im stuck.

This is my code:

http://pastebin.com/EyHBSFG6

In short, I have a form (attivitaType) that contain a sub-form (goalsType) added dynamically. When I submit the form, symfony return an error because the collection type dont transform data in Goalsboard entity, but try to pass it to the adder of Attivita entity as array.

Sorry for my English not excellent and thank you very much for the attention.

Comment: I can also add the twig code... Maybe it can be usefull http://pastebin.com/fWwq5jGr

Comment: Please add relevant code _in your question_. Thanks.

Comment: Solved. In my Goalsboard class I forget top put:     
public function setDefaultOptions(
    \Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
    ) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'InnovApp\Bundle\GameRivieraDeiCedriBundle\Entity\Goalsboard',
        ));
    }
So symfony dont know where have to pick the entity. Thanks anyway !! :)